# Comments not shown in wordpress - wp_list_comments(), comments_form()

Tags: database, wordpress, caching

In 90% of the cases, that is refreshing the same page, functions  **wp_list_comments()**, **comments_form()**, **has_comments()** and other functions alike aren't yielding the expected results.

So I refresh the same page and these functions return different results, for example either 0 comments, 5 or 21 comments, while no other user is using the database since it's a test system with XAMPP. It's noticeable that only values 0, 5 and 21 seem to pop up for the numer of comments.

Looking further down the call stack I could notice that sometimes $wpdb->has_comments() returns 0 although the post contains comments.

I suspect this may be something related to wordpress caching system of my version 4.5 and the only issue I found on their bug tracker was related to including wp_list_comments() twice in the same file, which is not the case. Updating to latest version also does not solve this.

I have noticed that the below debug log was printed in the debug.log file, but only **once** although the page has been reloaded hundreds of times:

```
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to
use near 'WHERE  AND comment_parent IN (61,62,66)  ORDER BY comment_date_gmt 
ASC, comment_' at line 1 for query   WHERE  AND comment_parent IN (61,62,66)  
ORDER BY comment_date_gmt ASC, comment_ID ASC made by 
require('C:\xampp\htdocs\boxify\chef\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php'),
require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\boxify\chef\wordpress\wp-includes\template
loader.php'), include('C:\xampp\htdocs\boxify\chef\wordpress\wp-
content\themes\mytheme\single.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, 
load_template, <...more files here...>, comments_template,
WP_Comment_Query->__construct, WP_Comment_Query->query, WP_Comment_Query-
>get_comments, WP_Comment_Query->fill_descendants
```

Issue occurs on multiple self-hosted wordpress installations.

With other themes, like twentysixteen or others I don't see this sort of behavior, so it's definitely something wrong on my side and I suspect the caching configuration, which I didn't touch.

Also, I've checked for wp_reset_postdata() usage and there's none in my single template. Add theme support is used for comments and everything. Any hint or some direction in which I should dig further would be great!

Comment: Do you find any error in the console or the debug log file?

Comment: Updated the question with the only debug log printed with $wbdb->last_error that curiously was ouput only once in debug.log. It's interesting because the page has been reloaded hundreds of times with different results and yet only this one error was ever printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the issue was.

Somewhere in the code, in the middle of THE MAIN LOOP a file was included with get_template_part() and in that file a function running a new WP_Query was missing wp_reset_postdata(). This caused the global $post to become corrupt, at least from my point of view.

Since that WP_Query was used to get a random post, this caused comments to be shown for that random post. Sometimes they existed, other times they didn't.

Also, further functions like get_next_post() and get_previous_post() that were relying on $post were now returning results relative to the new random post instead of the old post, as expected.

Only when I noticed these adjacent functions were returning invalid results did I understand where the issue was.